# OOP - Login system with database

Tags: java, oop, class-diagram

I am trying to figure out how to create an login system with an database correctly in Java.

I am suck on where I should have my login an register functions. Should this be in my main app, should it be part of my constructor, or should it be functions inside my User class?

What is the most common and prefered way to do it, or is the way a whole third one I didn't think of?

Answer (score 0):

Login and register can be functions inside the User class. Because it is a functionality for the user. But this will be completely opinion based. It depends upto you how you want to design it.

Comment: There are no standards in Java when doing this?

Comment: No, they aren't. It depends upon you. I can also go on making a completely different class which is having this functionality. There I can pass an instance of User class to login /register